# Monero daemon events for incoming transactions

Tags: daemon, rpc

Suppose I have a database with 10k users each having a dedicated wallet. Based on my knowledge, the only way to know *in real time* when funds have been sent to those wallets is by constantly pooling each one of them - overkill.

What is the most efficient way to accomplish that?

Comment: There isn't really an efficient way of doing it. You'd be much better off using subaddresses/accounts so you only scan once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Based on my knowledge, the only way to know in real time when funds have been sent to those wallets is by constantly pooling each one of them

You don't need to poll. There are 2 options available to get a realtime notification: [ZMQ](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/docs/ZMQ.md) or [--tx-notify](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/10902/7493).

If you have each users funds tracked through subaddresses, you only need a single wallet running that is doing the notifications.